# How to figure out which prettyphoto lightbox is currently open?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, prettyphoto

In the prettyPhoto changePictureCallback function, I'd like to know which lightbox is currently open. Currently I'm doing this:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  deeplinking : false,
  counter_separator_label : ' of ',
  gallery_markup : '',
  social_tools : '',
  slideshow : false,
  changepicturecallback: function(){
    //do stuff
    id_to_find = $(".active_lightbox").attr('href');
  },
  opacity : 0.29
}).click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active_lightbox');
});
```

This way, when the anchor gets clicked on, is gets active_lightbox put onto it.
However, this doesnt play very well. I can end up having multiple active_lightbox elements, and also, it doesnt put that class on the "active_lightbox" if I use the next button within the lightbox gallery.
So, how do I tell which lightbox is currently open with jquery/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options here, but the one that jumps out to me:

It looks like you're trying to working with a few `<a rel="prettyPhoto##">` where `##` is the gallery or photo number? If this is the case, I recommend something like this:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").each(function(index, elm)
  var $elm = $(elm);
  // an arbitrary ID based on its order in the DOM
  var photo_id = index;
  // returns the ## from rel="prettyPhoto##"
  var gallery_id = $(elm).attr('rel').replace("prettyPhoto", ""); 
  $elm.prettyPhoto({
    ...
    changepicturecallback: function(){
      // do stuff
      // photo_id
      // gallery_id
      // elm and $elm
    },
    ...
  });
```

**OR** you could add a little more markup but be more precise by making use of `data-` tags.

**RESOURCES**

- http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto
- http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: <a href="#lightbox_wyMILFBNOrm" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
 //description in here.
</a>

Comment: That is how all of my anchors look. The important thing is that all of these need to have the same rel attribute, with the same gallery name to be in the same gallery. Can you provide an example of an anchor that would work with your strategy? Also, where exactly does the index come from? I understand that it needs to be iterated, but I dont see how it is iterated. By the way, the wyMILF... is a unique ID for what is being show in the lightbox

Comment: Never mind, I glanced at the jQuery.each doc and it is now self-explanatory. Thank you very much Nick, I didn't think about doing something like this!